# How to uninstall NeoBundle in OS X?

Tags: vimrc, macos, installing

I was trying to revamp the vim editor so I installed NeoBundle but I didn't like it. How can I uninstall it completely?

I followed the installation instructions given in the [readme](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim#quick-start):

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/master/bin/install.sh > install.sh`
$ sh ./install.sh`
```

Should I just erase the lines in the `.vimrc` file?

Comment: How did you installed it? Did you used a plugin manager (If yes which one)? Also did you add some configuration for NeoBundle in your vimrc?

Comment: I used the `$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/master/bin/install.sh > install.sh
 $ sh ./install.sh ` script that gives the author and yes I added some configuration in order to include some packages. @statox

Comment: Arf I'm not clever today I mistook NeoBundle for NeoComplete, it would be stupid to use a plugin manger to install a plugin manager :-) I don't know this plugin manager well enough to be useful here, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry. I think NeoComplete is a plugin from the same author Shougo but thanks either way. Have a nice day @statox. (:

Comment: Indeed that the same (great) author. Have a good one too.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the lines in .vimrc and delete the folder ~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim

The installation is just cloning a github repo and then loading with the lines you added to .vimrc

Comment: Hi, I just did that but the plugins are still there. Is that ok?

Comment: If you're not using them (I.e. They're not included/referenced on .vimrc) it's safe to delete the folders of those plugins.